# Android - Why RecyclerView is not displaying on the device?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-viewholder, android-adapterview

I just created a simple `RecyclerView` project which will show the name of fruits. But when i run the file it is not showing anything. In fact my whole source code is just fine.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.fruits.myrecyclerview;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String[] fruits = {"Apple", "Mango", "Pineapple", "Orange"};
    FruitsAdapter fruitsAdapter;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );
        fruitsAdapter = new FruitsAdapter( fruits );
        recyclerView = findViewById( R.id.recycler_view );
        recyclerView.setAdapter( fruitsAdapter );
    }
}
```

**FruitsAdapter.java**

```
package com.fruits.myrecyclerview;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class FruitsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FruitsAdapter.FruitsView>{
    String[] fruits;

    public FruitsAdapter( String[] fruits){
        this.fruits = fruits;
    }

    public class FruitsView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView textView;
        public FruitsView( View view ){
            super(view);
            textView = (TextView) view.findViewById( R.id.fruit_list );
        }

    }
    @Override
    public FruitsView onCreateViewHolder( @NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType ) {
        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater
                .from( parent.getContext() )
                .inflate( R.layout.fruites_list, parent, false );
        return new FruitsView( linearLayout );
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder( @NonNull FruitsView holder, int position ) {
        holder.textView.setText( fruits[position] );
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount( ) {
        return fruits.length;
    }
}
```

**fruites_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fruit_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Something"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the LayoutManager, add

```
recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
```

Comment: It tells the RecyclerView how to lay out its elements. Without it, nothing will be displayed. This one lays items in a single vertical column. You can lay them horizontally, or use a GridLayout manager for multiple columns.

Comment: What do you mean by this? But i already added the view holder then why to add the `layout manager`? Can you please give me an example to clear this logic?

Comment: A recyclerview is a modular component, it offloads responsibilities to other components. One of them is the LayoutManager, which computes how to position the elements. Unless you give the RecyclerView a LayoutManager (either one of the 3 provided ones, or your own), nothing can be displayed because the RecyclerView, by itself, doesn't know how to lay the items on the screen. Check the RecyclerView documentation for further details.

Comment: One more thing, does the `RecyclerView` automatically optimize the list of items internally or no do i have to do something special?

Comment: I'm not certain what you mean by "optimize", but if you mean recycle items and re-use them as they flow off the screen, then yes, it does that.